# How do make wait get response for an ajax call to finish?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to wait for a response before the next round. Please help me.

I want to wait for a response before it starts to do the job in the way that it works now without a response.

```
function run(url,max,dd,t,u,p)
{
    for(index=1;index<=max;index++) 
    {
        aurl = index;               

        $.get("post.php?u=" + u + "&t=" + t + "&p=" + p + "&page=" + aurl + "&dd=" + dd,
        function(data){     
            if(data === "")
            {
                $('#acount').text(index);
                return;                 
            }
            else
            {
                $('#acount').text(data);

            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea. You could wrap your code in function and call it recursively and break it if stop condition is met. Something like this:

```
function run(url,max,dd,t,u,p) {

    var index = 0;
    var iteration = function(){
        index++;
        if (index > max) return;
        $.get("...",
              function(data){
               ...
               iteration()
            })
       }
}
```